# Documenting Function Macros with Doxygen

Tags: c, doxygen

I have some code of this sort:

header.h

```
#define abc() xyz()
```

code.c

```
#include "header.h"

void xyz(){
    int a = 24;
}

void func_lmn(){
    abc();
}
```

When I run doxygen on this code, the call graoh for function func_lmn() does not contain either abc() or xyz(). Is it possble to do the same?

Following flags have been turned on:

```
ENABLE_PREPROCESSOR = YES
MACRO_EXPANSION = YES
SKIP_FUNCTION_MACROS = NO
```

Comment: xyz() is a function defined in another file. I'll edit the question to make it more clear.

Comment: What happens if you do: `#define abc xyz` instead?

Comment: Makes no difference. @2501

Comment: What happens if you declare abc as an inline function instead of a macro ? (even if maybe that is not really what you want)